# Arduous selection statement from a table in Hive format

Tags: sql, select, hive

Please, help my. 
I have a trouble writing a select statement for a table and would appreciate any help. Any SQL syntax is also fine.
[image: The image shows the source table and result box is the destination for which the select statement is to be written]

Excuse me, I simplified the initial data. The real data is the same.

```
declare @actions table
(
    actionId varchar(20),
    person int,
    direction bit,
    dt datetime
)
```

insert into @actions values ('1-23', 1, 1, '20180201 09:00:15')
insert into @actions values ('1-25', 2, 0, '20180201 09:00:25')
insert into @actions values ('21-43', 2, 1, '20180201 09:05:52')
insert into @actions values ('2-23', 1, 1, '20180201 09:10:55')
insert into @actions values ('16-2', 2, 1, '20180201 09:15:02')
insert into @actions values ('11-13', 1, 0, '20180201 09:15:41')
insert into @actions values ('2-33', 1, 1, '20180201 09:20:18')
insert into @actions values ('7-28', 2, 0, '20180201 09:20:54')
insert into @actions values ('1-25', 1, 0, '20180201 09:25:36')
insert into @actions values ('10-14', 2, 0, '20180201 09:25:37')
insert into @actions values ('10-58', 2, 1, '20180201 09:30:14')
insert into @actions values ('31-23', 1, 0, '20180201 09:30:32')
insert into @actions values ('11-27', 1, 1, '20180201 09:35:36')
insert into @actions values ('5-58', 2, 0, '20180201 09:35:45')
insert into @actions values ('8-68', 2, 1, '20180201 09:40:21')
insert into @actions values ('8-90', 2, 0, '20180201 09:45:36')

select * from @actions

Comment: Please paste the data directly into the question instead of as an image, preferably as insert statements as it will make answering the question much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways to do this - CTE, LAG functions, other. This is probably the simplest.

I have added insert statements for the first user only. Syntax is sql server but should work anywhere.

First the create and populate data:

```
declare @x table(id int, person int, direction int, dt datetime)
insert @x values (1,1,1,'2018-01-02 09:00'),(2,1,1,'2018-02-02 09:12'),(3,1,2,'2018-01-02 09:25')
,(4,1,1,'2018-01-02 09:30'),(5,1,2,'2018-01-02 09:45'),(6,1,2,'2018-01-02 09:50')
```

Now the query:

```
select * from (
select x.person, x.id,x.dt,x2.id id2,x2.dt dt2
from @x x
left join @x x2 on x2.id=x.id+1 and x2.person=x.person and x2.direction=2
where x.direction=1
union
select x.person, null,null,x.id,x.dt
from @x x
left join @x x2 on x2.id=x.id-1 and x2.person=x.person 
where x.direction=2 and x2.direction<>1
) q order by isnull(id2,id2)
```

And the results:

```
person  id      dt                      id2     dt2
1       1       2018-01-02 09:00:00.000 NULL    NULL
1       2       2018-02-02 09:12:00.000 3       2018-01-02 09:25:00.000
1       4       2018-01-02 09:30:00.000 5       2018-01-02 09:45:00.000
1       NULL    NULL                    6       2018-01-02 09:50:00.000
```